# Is ruby on rails plugin, acts_as_ferret, very buggy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, plugins, autosuggest, acts-as-ferret

I am doing a very simple search on my DB using acts_as_ferret.  I put this in my "Venue" model:

```
acts_as_ferret :fields => [:name, :city]
```

And this is in my controller search action:

```
@t = Venue.find_by_contents(params[:search]+'~')
```

and then I just render the results.

```
render :text => @t.to_json, :success => true, :status => :ok
```

If I run a quick test:

```
http://localhost:3000/venue/list?search=The
```

I see in my log that the proper query "The~" is being executed on the index.  However, I get no results.  I definitely have a few "Venues" with the word "The" in the name field.

Since this is a very simple search and acts_as_ferret is used quite a bit, I tried rebuilding the index to see if it was corrupted....no dice

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Ferret has been very well known for corrupting indexes.

I recommend switching over to another searching plugin like [Thinking Sphinx](http://ts.freelancing-gods.com/). You can [watch the Railscast about it](http://railscasts.com/episodes/120-thinking-sphinx) in order to learn more.

Comment: Agreed - avoid AAF.  There are better options out there: ThinkingSphinx and even Solr if you need everything that Lucene provides

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem might be that "the" is defined as a stopword- an extremely common word that is not indexed because it would just return every document. You can configure your stopword list.

I would consider using Solr if you are having problems with Ferret.